# MessageDigges md5 differs from the database md5 string

Tags: java

```
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
   String md5password = new String(md.digest("test".getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8");
```

I have the same string `"test"` in my database, but here I get something different like this:

```
�k�F!�s��N�&'��
```

database:

```
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
new String(md.digest("test".getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8");
```

You're trying to decode the result of the MD5 digest as if it were a UTF-8 string. It's not. It's not text at all - it's just binary data. What you're doing is like trying to load an image or music file as a string - it's just a bad idea.

It looks like your database is either storing it as binary data and showing you a hex representation, or storing it as hex. I suggest you do the same. There are *lots* of Stack Overflow questions about converting byte arrays to hex in Java, so that part should be simple.

Comment: wow, I've fixed it using byteToHex convert functions , thank you very much, accept in 5 minutes